How can i use Gradio's Ul components in standalone JavaScript applications outside ofthe Gradioenvironment?
I'd like to port Gradio's JavaScript component to a React app.For example, i hope to be able to use the audio component independently.enter image description here
However, as a newbie, I don't really know how to import it.I followed the doc's instructions and tried to install, but it failed.enter image description here
If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.
PS:The link of docs text

Please provide more details about the error you encountered when trying to install the component.
